# Error while rendering the javascript file while trying to authenticate using firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am trying to design a simple login system using firebase.

Here is my below app.js code that contains the functions for post login, signup and logout.

```
(function(){
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "Apikey",
    authDomain: "login-8a262.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "firebasedb url",
    projectId: "login-8a262",
    storageBucket: "login-8a262.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "737178664611"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  //Get all the elements 
  const txtEmail= document.getElementById('txtEmail');
   const txtPassword= document.getElementById('txtPassword');
    const btnLogin= document.getElementById('btnLogin');
     const btnSignUp= document.getElementById('btnSignUp');
      const btnLogout= document.getElementById('btnLogout');


      //Add the Login Event 
      btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e=>{
          //Get the email and password
          const email = txtEmail.value;
          const pass = txtPassword.value;
          const auth = firebase.auth();
          //Sign in
          const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
          promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

});
 //Add the signup event
 btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e=>{
     console.log('in signup now');
      //Get the email and password
          const email = txtEmail.value;
          const pass = txtPassword.value;
          const auth = firebase.auth();
          //Sign in
          const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
          promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

 });

  btnLogout.addEventListener('click', e=>{
      firebase.auth().signOut();
  });

 //Add a realtime listener 
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    if(firebaseUser)
    {
     console.log(firebaseUser);

     btnLogout.classList.remove('hide');
    }
    else
    {
     console.log(firebaseUser);
     console.log('not logged in');
     btnLogout.classList.add('hide');
    }
 });





}());
```

Here is my below html Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Firebase Web Quickstart</title>

    <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,500" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">

        <input id="txtPassword" type="Password"
        placeholder="Password">

        <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-action">
        Log in
        </button>

        <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-secondary">
        Sign Up
        </button>

        <button id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-action hide">
        Log Out
        </button>
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

I am not able to figure out why I am getting the below errors for the addEventListener methods.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
        at app.js:23
        at app.js:70

Comment: Try moving the js file to the bottom of your document? There seems to be nothing telling the js to wait for the DOM to load before trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add firebase sdk script.

```
    <script src="//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="your-script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: The Firebase SDK is being included as far as I can see: `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>`

Comment: must have overlooked it. oh well...